# C# Create 3x3 Matrix from vector

Tags: c#, matrix, vector

I have a vector and I want to create a Matrix from this vector. The Matrix3 should be 3times Vector3. How is it possible? Do I have to create a new public static?
The Code below shows my Vector3.

```
public static Vector3 VectorMultiply(Vector3 v, Matrix3 m) 
              { 
                  Vector3 vr = new Vector3(); 
                  vr.x = v.x * m.X.x + v.y * m.Y.x + v.z * m.Z.x; 
                  vr.y = v.x * m.X.y + v.y * m.Y.y + v.z * m.Z.y; 
                  vr.z = v.x * m.X.z + v.y * m.Y.z + v.z * m.Z.z; 
                  return (vr);
```